# How can I implement auto complete for a text box in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I implement auto complete for a text box in ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [autocomplete jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). And here's a tutorial on how to [integrate with ASP.NET MVC](http://flux88.com/blog/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 1):

I developed an html extension in the form of plugin, to use the jquery ui autocomplete but in a very simple and dynamic. the syntax was something like this here

```
       $@Html.AutoCompleteFor(model => model.Id, x => x.Code , "List")
```

I left all the source code available (suggestions are welcome) and a zip file containing all the necessary files. Hope that helps!

Project URL http://autocompletemvc.codeplex.com/releases/view/70140

Bin files http://autocompletemvc.codeplex.com/releases/70140/download/259741

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jquery?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/